# Displaying PHP/SQL Query on Webpage for Debugging Purpose

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a PHP/MYSQL based database. When a query is not working, often during debugging i thought that it would be helpful if I could see the processed query. Because may be the problematic processed query is different from the one I coded. How can I see the processed query? Here is my simplified php controller code:

```
<?php
$patientid = "3";
$patientname = "Khan";
$patientcity = "Osaka";
$Result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT id, name, city FROM patient-table WHERE id= '".$patientid."' ');
If(!$Result){
   echo 'An error was encountered during fetching patient's data, error details: '. mysqli_error($link);
}
//Code for displaying results of query
?>
```

Any Help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way to do it. I will show you how to do it and then how to remove the query displaying code after you have done debugging.

**To Display Query**
First save your query in a variable like:

```
$patientquery = 'SELECT id, name, city FROM patient-table WHERE id = ' . '$patientid';
```

Then to process the query you have to use:

```
$Result = mysqli_query($link, $patientquery);
```

You can see the processed query by simply echoing the $patientquery :

```
echo $patientquery;
```

Here is your code with above  changes:

```
<?php
$patientid = "3";
$patientname = "Khan";
$patientcity = "Osaka";
$patientquery = 'SELECT id, name, city FROM patient-table WHERE id = ' . $patientid;
$Result = mysqli_query($link, $patientquery);
If(!$Result){
   echo 'An error was encountered during fetching patient's data, error details: '. mysqli_error($link);
}
echo $patientquery; // to display processed query
//Code for displaying results of query
?>
```

**To Disable Query Displaying Code**
When you are done with debugging you can simply disable the line displaying the processed query by adding comments slashes as:

```
//echo $patientquery;
```

Comment: thanks a lotttt for such a detailed answer. I have checked your code. Its 100% Working. Thankss

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you assign it as a simple variable?

```
<?php
$patientid = "3";
$patientname = "Khan";
$patientcity = "Osaka";
$query = 'SELECT id, name, city FROM patient-table WHERE id= '".$patientid."' ';
$Result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
If(!$Result){
   echo 'An error was encountered during fetching patients data using query, '.$query.' , error details: '. mysqli_error($link);
}
//Code for displaying results of query
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your query in a variable and referencing that variable when running the query.

Then you can simply echo the query variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem :
your `echo` statement has the problem the apostrophe`'` in the patient's is ending your string there itself. Check that out. Otherwise you have used the correct way of seeing the query.